# Retrieve pdf from azure blob-storage

Tags: c#, pdf, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to retrieve pdf documents from my azure blob-storage. I am getting the document, but when I try to open it, it tells me that it cant read the data.

```
[HttpGet("GetFromBlob")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetFileFromBlob(string id)
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionString");

        CloudBlobClient BlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer c1 = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("blobName");

        if (await c1.ExistsAsync())
        {
            CloudBlob file = c1.GetBlobReference("FileReference");

            if (await file.ExistsAsync())
            {
                await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
                Stream blobStream = file.OpenReadAsync().Result;
                return File(blobStream, file.Properties.ContentType, file.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("File does not exist");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Container does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Turns out that my file format was wrong

Comment: What is the code that tries to open it and what is the actual Exception detail?

Comment: Also, your method is async so you should not be using `.Result`.

Comment: Adobe acrobat reader tells me that it cant open it, because filetype is not supported or the file is damaged. If I open it with IE, I can see the data. Feels like the datatype is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please try use the code below, which works fine at my side:

In the code block `if(await file.ExistsAsync())`:

```
        if (await file.ExistsAsync())
        {
            await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
            var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
            return File(stream, "application/pdf");
        }
```

Comment: Hello, if the answer works, please help mark it as an answer. Thanks.